# how to make the program read the path of second boost library

Tags: boost

I am trying to compile a program that makes use of threads and lock free queues. I am working on a system (RHEL) that is a part of another system that already has a boost library but an older version 1.44. Therefore, I build/install the boost library version 1.56 from the source in another directory.
However, when I try to compile the program with the following command I am getting the following error:-

g++ -I/data/ojaved/boost_install -L/data/ojaved/boost_install/lib -pthread -lboost_thread test_boost.cxx

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:17:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
             from test_boost.cxx:2:
/usr/include/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:29:4: error: #error "Threading support            
unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
#  error "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with    
BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:0,
             from test_boost.cxx:2:
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:67:9: error: #error "Sorry, no boost   
threads are available for this platform."
#       error "Sorry, no boost threads are available for this platform."
     ^
In file included from test_boost.cxx:2:0:
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:19:2: error: #error "Boost threads unavailable on    
this platform"
#error "Boost threads unavailable on this platform"
^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:11:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,
             from test_boost.cxx:2:
/usr/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:18:2: error: #error "Boost threads unavailable on   
this platform"
#error "Boost threads unavailable on this platform"
^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:13:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,
             from test_boost.cxx:2:
/usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:19:2: error: #error "Boost threads   
unavailable on this platform"
#error "Boost threads unavailable on this platform"
^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread_group.hpp:9:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:24,
             from test_boost.cxx:2:
/usr/include/boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp:18:2: error: #error "Boost threads unavailable   
on this platform"
#error "Boost threads unavailable on this platform"
^
test_boost.cxx:3:36: fatal error: boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: No such file or directory

#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
                                ^
compilation terminated.
```

It seems to me that it still cannot find the path of the new boost library.

Comment: Waht do yo see on `/data/ojaved/boost_install` path?

Comment: This is the installation directory that I created. It contains lib and include folders.

Comment: What is the compiler version you are using?

Comment: Sorry for replying late, but I have managed to compile it, the issue was I was not referring to the path correctly. Changed the path            from -I/data/ojaved/boost_install to  -I/data/ojaved/boost_install/include when compiling. It worked after doing that.